# FasterCSV - raising MalformedCSVError when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, fastercsv

Sample data:

`"iWine","Barcode","Location","Bin","Size","Valuation","Price","StoreName",\
"PurchaseDate","Note","Vintage","Wine","Locale","Country","Region","SubRegion",\
"Appellation","Producer","SortProducer","Type","Color","Category","Varietal",\
"MasterVarietal","Designation","Vineyard","WA","WS","IWC","BG","WE","JR",\
"RH","JG","GV","JK","LD","CW","CT","MY","BeginConsume","EndConsume"`

`"334142","15240542","Cellar","","750ml","","0","","","","2003",\

"Bodegas y Viñedos Alión Ribera del Duero","Spain, Castilla y León, Ribera del Duero","Spain",\

"Castilla y León","Unknown","Ribera del Duero","Bodegas y Viñedos Alión",\

"Alión, Bodegas y Viñedos","Red","Red","Dry","Tempranillo","Tempranillo","Unknown","Unknown",\

"","","","","","","","","","","","","91.3333333333333","","2011","2021"`

FasterCSV insists on raising MalformedCSVError when parsing this data, specifically thrown around line 1616 in faster_csv.rb

```
raise MalformedCSVError unless in_quotes
```

Comment: This is difficult to read. Can you edit it onto several more lines?

Comment: Could it be the last comma on a line?  Maybe either use a pair of empty quotes ("") or take out the last comma?  Not familiar with the class, but it sounds like it wants EVERYTHING in quotes by your error.

Answer (score 0):

Also - did you check out related posts about the encoding?

[How do I import using FasterCSV a row with a name like "Ciarán"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328250/how-do-i-import-using-fastercsv-a-row-with-a-name-like-ciaran)

Comment: I did. Doing some more testing (and remembering a similar issue I had a while back), I copy and pasted the contents of the csv into a new file, and it works as expected. Thoughts on that? Maybe came through (it was exported from Google Spreadsheet) with mucked up char encoding or something along those lines?

Comment: Yea, I'm not really sure.  Do you specify the flag on the command?  Seems like it would be easier than ensuring your file was in the right format?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the issues you are having are due to the non-ascii characters.

Try replacing them with non-accents, and see if it works. If it does, you must use the :encoding option on FasterCSV to match your file's format.